# Where do I put 'mcmodel=medium' in order to tackle "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol..." issue

Tags: c++, netbeans, out-of-memory

So I'm having an issue with my generic method in C++... When I have the method in a namespace in the same class as my main it works.

```
void
displayVector(auto const& vector)
{
    for (auto const& element : vector)
    {
        cout << element;
    }
}
```

However, when it is called from another CPP class (a Utility class) it gives me the "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol..." issue.

I'm told that putting mcmodel=medium somewhere would fix this, After searching around online and investigating my Cygwin files I can't find what file location would be correct.

I am using Cygwin and Netbeans IDE 8.1 (Windows 8)

Thanks.

Comment: That goes in the command line to the compiler/linker.

Comment: Great at least I know I'm looking at the g++ commands anyway, I can't find a way to set the compiler to permanently have the 'mcmodel=medium' setting permanently though, still looking about though.

Comment: If you're using a makefile, add the flag to CFLAGS (or create a custom compile call)